# Padding reduces Icon size in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I want ripple effect on my icon. But when i increase padding it reduces the icon size 
when padding is 5dp it looks something like this [image]

But when i increase padding size to 12dp it looks like this [image]

My ImageView xml

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/institute_search_item_request_icon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/request_institute_red_icon__shape"
            android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_foreground"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_link_white_24dp" />
```

request_institute_red_icon__shape.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

and ripple_foreground.xml

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/colorAccent">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: why u need padding?

Comment: use margin do that.

Comment: @ Bhuvanesh i want ripple colour around icon. Please correct me if i am doing some silly mistake

Comment: Yes padding will sure reduce image size if it doesn't contain extra padding.

Comment: @Piyush but then how can i achieve ripple effect

Comment: Ripple effect does not have to do anything with padding.

Comment: just read my question today after almost 4 years. And I feel i was so stupid to add padding for ripple effect

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding, it will shrink your icon.
In you `imageview` just add this line to get ripple effect

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

To get oval ripple:

**round_background.xml**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/colorAccent"
    android:radius="your_radius"    // try radius
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_background" />
</ripple>
```

**red_background.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/red_color"/>/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I have already tried it. It does not give me oval shape ripple effect. Its appear in ractangle shape using this solution

Comment: No it does not have any effect